# How to add a mouse-up event?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, netbeans-6.9

Right-click > Events > Action > actionPerformed adds the mouse-down event to a NetBeans JButton. How is the mouse-up event added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Net Beans do this :

```
Right=Click -> Events -> Mouse -> MouseReleased.
```

Hope that might help

Regards

Comment: Could have jumped out and bit me.

Answer (score 3):

Through the NetBeans IDE:
    RightClick->Events->Mouse->MousePressed

Or, MouseClicked, MouseReleased, etc.

OR......

Make your class implement MouseListener and than use this to add it to your button.

```
myButton.addMouseListener(this)
```

Then implement this method to fulfill the interface:

```
public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            myMouseClickedMethod(evt);
        }
```

Comment: :(, if  you will implement MouseListener than you have to define all the methods, mouseClicked(), mousePressed(), mouseReleased(), mouseEntered() and mouseExited(), not just one will be enough to fulfill the interface.  Regards

Comment: hmmmn, while this is true you can simply do nothing for the methods you are not interested in. But that is of course only if you want to circumvent the 3-4 click option in the NetBeans Designer. Which was something I just did today to simplify my code for over 10 JTextfields.

Comment: Or you can extends MouseAdapter Class to do what you did, only one method will do, which ever method you need. +1 for the info though. Warm Regards

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. For my implementation I am okay though, easier to put a comment in each method saying I'm ignoring that event than to make my own interface that extends MouseAdapter - As the class I'm working with already extends JPanel. Plus I am implementing ActionListener and KeyListener on top of that. Thank you though, this may prove useful in the future :)